# Google form auto assign different staff once submitted

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

Im creating student list for our library. The student will submit their info (Name and ID) through google form. Once the student submit, I would like to assign each student to different staff (total of 5 staffs) (Column D). Something like screenshot below. Could someone help me get this done? BTW, is it possible to send email too to the assign staff email?

[image]

Comment: Can I ask you about your question. 1. About `is it possible to send email too to the assign staff email?`, in this case it is required to use Google Apps Script. How about this? 2. If you use Google Apps Script, about `Could someone help me get this done?`, can you provide your current script? By this, we can think of the issue of the script. 3. Can I ask you about the detail logic of `Google form auto assign different staff once submitted` you expect?

Comment: Just like @Tanaike has mentioned, can you please provide what you have tried so far in order to achieve this? Moreover, can you provide more details about your task?

Comment: @Tanaike Dear Tanaike, thank you for your reply. During the weekend, I found out that it is easier if Im setup one dummy tab that contains staff name, then use this formula to get the students info into the dummy tab. `=IFERROR(DGET(StudentDetails!$A$1:$H$25,"Name",{"No";A2}),"")`

Comment: I also found this tutorial to send email from the sheet. [link]https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails. Now I just need to figure out, how to run this script using button on each row one by one instead of run 1 time for all data.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula for getting the students information into the dummy tab:

```
=IFERROR(DGET(StudentDetails!$A$1:$H$25,"Name",{"No";A2}),"")
```

And then just use [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails) Apps Script tutorial for sending emails.

**Reference**

- [Sending emails from a Spreadsheet Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails)